# Angularjs: Error: [ng:areq] ResevationController not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**MainController.js**

```
(function(){

    var eateryControllers=angular.module('eateryControllers',[]);

    eateryControllers.controller('MainController',function(){

        var mainCtrl=this;
    });

})();
```

**ReservationController.js**

```
(function(){

    var eateryControllers=angular.module('eateryControllers');

    eateryControllers.controller('ReservationController',reservationController);
    function reservationController(){
        var resvnCtrl=this;
        resvnCtrl.user={};
    }

})();
```

I am creating module in first file and reusing the same module in second file.

**Error**

```
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/ng/areq?p0=ReservationController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:6:416
    at qb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:22:131)
    at Sa (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:22:218)
    at b.$get (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:80:81)
    at g.link (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.min.js:7:268)
    at aa
```

Comment: are these two files included in your HTML, and *in the correct order*?

Comment: I think your ReservationController.js file is getting call before MainController.js file so the module is not getting initiated

Comment: you probably should put your 'reservationController' function above the definition of your angular controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should put your 'reservationController' function above the definition of your angular controller once youre trying to use a function before defining it

```
(function(){

    var eateryControllers=angular.module('eateryControllers');
    function reservationController(){
        var resvnCtrl=this;
        resvnCtrl.user={};
    }
    eateryControllers.controller('ReservationController',reservationController);

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your controller as 'ReservationController' and used in your code as 'ResevationController'. Error is due to typo

Comment: He's not doing that. Read the error description pasted on code. He just missed the name on title that probably he wroted manualy

Comment: @Guilherme Ferreira you are right. I should have seen the stack trace before answering that.  Thanks for pointing